# SQL: Why SELECT by many rows are faster than by many columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Why SQL `SELECT * FROM T_ROW;` is faster than `SELECT * FROM T_COLUMN;`?

The total amount of data in the tables is the same.

Explain:

```
T_COLUMN:
Seq Scan on t_column  (cost=0.00..2.05 rows=5 width=1995) (actual time=0.014..0.018 rows=5 loops=1)
    Buffers: shared hit: 2
Planning time: 0.184 ms
Execution time: 0.093 ms


T_ROW:
Seq Scan on t_row  (cost=0.00..4.00 rows=100 width=165) (actual time=0.015..0.024 rows=100 loops=1)
    Buffers: shared hit: 3
Planning time: 0.047 ms
Execution time: 0.040 ms
```

TABLES:

```
T_COLUMN
|| c1 | c2 | c3 | ..... | c99 | c100 ||
```

with **5** rows

```
T_ROW
|| c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 ||
```

with **100** rows

Comment: More column metadata to transfer/query planner to go through/something could be it. We’re talking a few microseconds of difference here. If you want meaningful results, use a meaningful input size.

Comment: `0.093` milliseconds vs. `0.040` milliseconds isn't really that much slower- That could well be caused by caching effects or other things going on on the server. You might also want to use `explain (analyze, buffers, timing)` to see more details

Comment: Buffers: shared hit: '100Column' = 2, '100Row' = 3. I'm wondering why one case is always faster than another at least 2 times. It is not an accident... If there were 1000 columns vs 1000 rows, will the difference be increased?

Comment: I assume when you put same data to 5 rows you use long values, thus TOAST, thus data is compressed and takes less space. regarding 1k question - try and report - I think effect should be even more clear